# Swift Generic empty Array & Dictionary initialization

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, generics

I try to solve generic condition that I want to return empty array or dictionary when the Element is Optional Type.

**Code:**

```
private func findOut<T: Any>() -> T {
    
    if T.self is String.Type {
        
        return "STRING" as! T
    }
    
    if T.self is Array<Any>.Type {
        
        return [] as! T
    }
    
    if T.self is Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>.Type {
        
        return [:] as! T
    }
    
    return "Invalid" as! T
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let stringValue: [String] = self.findOut()
print(stringValue)
```

In this use case, I expect emtpy array even if it's anything in the array instead of String. i.e., `[[String:Any]], [(String,Int)], etc.` So, the Element of the array is unknown constrain. but I want to return empty array which is valid return. Same for Dictionary too. How can I achive it using my generic function? Thanks for your help.

**Update:**

I've found solution with string checking, but I suspect there is easy alternative way to do that, if any please help,

```
let name = String(describing: T.self)
print(name)

if name.prefix(6) == "Array<" {
    
    return [] as! T
}

if name.prefix(11) == "Dictionary<" {
    
    return [:] as! T
}
```

Comment: Generics with `Any` and this kind of type check at runtime smells and fights the framework. Be aware that generic types are not covariant, so the check `if T.self is Array<Any>.Type` will never succeed unless the generic concrete type is really `Any`. Same applies to Dictionary.

Comment: The line `return "Invalid" as! T` will allways crash your application. As `T` cannot be of type `String` at this point.

Comment: What is the point of this function, maybe some solution could be worked out but it doesn’t feel worth it without a reason. I mean why not do `let stringValue: [String] = []` since you always know the type anyway?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, The use is, I'm using an 3rd party rest API and created api_client for the whole api's and it's helpers. I've function `get<T:Any>` where `any` is `resultData` of the `json`. The result data sometimes `nil` for some api's which isn't error but I can't return `T` as `null` so that only I go for empty array or dict if the resultData is nil. Otherwise, I want to loss the common helper statement and move'em to each use-blocks. i.e., `T?`

Comment: So to start with it shouldn’t be T:Any but rather T:Decodable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is what to return for each type and I think a straightforward solution is to create a protocol for this and let any type that can be returned conform to this protocol.

We need a function that returns an empty or rather default value when the decoded result is nil. Since this is for decoded json we create a protocol that extends Decodable

```
protocol NonNilDecodable: Decodable {
    static func createEmpty() -> Self
}
```

And then we implement conformance to the new protocol for Array and Dictionary

```
extension Array: NonNilDecodable where Element: Decodable {
    static func createEmpty() -> Array<Element> {
        []
    }
}

extension Dictionary: NonNilDecodable where Key: Decodable, Value:Decodable {
    static func createEmpty() -> Dictionary<Key, Value> {
        [:]
    }
}
```

And then the function can make use of this protocol

```
func get<T: NonNilDecodable >(…) -> T { 
    // other code…
    return someOptionalResult ?? T.createEmpty()
}
```

The advantage of a solution like this is that it’s cleaner than using Any nd casting and it can easily be extended to other types if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, This makes more extra work brother. I've gone `String(describing: T.self)` & comparing dict or array. Also note that the T isn't always relays on JSON objects some times I need plain `Data.self`, `String.self` when the primary delegate == nil or the `Content-Type` isn't application/json. Seems My way I could compare `Decodable.self` too

Comment: Yes it’s more work but it’s a more stable solution. If you are trying to write a single function that should handle everything like json, binary data, plain text etc  I think you are doing yourself a disfavor and your better of with splitting it into different functions.

Comment: Yes correct. I should split. But I've priorities for data processing. In very frequent time I've process 10 or more JSON data. In this case `JSONSerialization` is faster than `JSONDecoder` as I've tested.  I've two kind of init in my struct for same information but different Json structure.  The json decoding is top priority comes first if it failes then only it test outs T.self which is lower priority infrequent calls.  Just sharing as Info <3